# Is there an Android SDK for Linux ppc64?

Tags: android, linux, powerpc

I'm trying to understand if there is an Android SDK available for Linux ppc64. I downloaded the Linux SDK tools only package from [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) (`android-sdk_r24.3.3-linux.tgz` at the time of downloading), but when I try to run `tools/android` from the downloaded package, I get an error message saying:

```
SWT folder `/home/user/android-sdk-linux/lib/ppc64` does not exist.
Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your installation.
```

It appears that the error is correct; only `x86` and `x86_64` directories exist in lib that contain `swt.jar` files.

I would assume, therefore, that the Android SDK is only available for Linux x86. But I can't find a definitive statement anywhere. Can someone confirm? If not, where would I get a ppc64 version of the SDK from?

Comment: Given that [this](https://github.com/zeldin/android-sdk-ppc) exists, it seems very likekly that only x86 / x86-64 are supported for Linux hosts, even though I haven't seen it explicitly stated anywhere.

Comment: You could try compiling the Android SDK for ppc64. I haven't been able to get it working, but you could always try that.