# Is there an Android SDK for Linux?

Tags: java, android, linux, sdk

I'm trying to understand if there is an Android SDK available for Linux ppc64. I downloaded the Linux SDK tools only package from here (android-sdk_r24.3.3-linux.tgz at the time of downloading), but when I try to run tools/android from the downloaded package, I get an error message saying:

SWT folder `/home/user/android-sdk-linux/lib/ppc64` does not exist.
Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your installation.

It appears that the error is correct; only x86 and x86_64 directories exist in lib that contain swt.jar files.

I would assume, therefore, that the Android SDK is only available for Linux x86. But I can't find a definitive statement anywhere. Can someone confirm? If not, where would I get a ppc64 version of the SDK from?

Comment: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.3.2.0/android-studio-ide-141.2178183-linux.zip

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31607693/is-there-an-android-sdk-for-linux-ppc64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would assume, therefore, that the Android SDK is only available for Linux x86. But I can't find a definitive statement anywhere. Can someone confirm?

I can confirm that there is no official distribution of the Android SDK for any architecture other than x86.

Now, some people have cross-compiled the toolchain to run on ARM, so I suppose there's nothing necessarily preventing somebody from taking similar steps to get it working on other architectures. That being said, since the PowerPC architecture has been largely ignored since the turn of the century, I doubt that anyone has had the itch to scratch.